# Strange max notation with mixed inside and outside indexes

Tags: notation

I've found a question regarding this notation on another board. I can't get it myself and decided to ask here. I don't know the source of the notation.

Usually under the $\max$ sign we have a definition of the set of the maximum search for the $\max$ argument. Here we have two indexed $x$. Is it "for each pair of such $x$"?

Furthermore, on the inside function there's an iteration over the same indices. Is it a poor choice of indices or I don't get something?

How this notation should be read? Is it widely used?

$$
\max_{(x_i),(x_{ij})} \left\{ -\sum_{i\in I} f_i x_i + \sum_{j\in J}\sum_{i\in I} p_{ij} x_{ij} \right\}.
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like two different sets of decision variables, both of which are called $x$.  I think it would be clearer as follows:
$$\max_{x, y} \left\{ -\sum_{i\in I} f_i x_i + \sum_{i\in I} \sum_{j\in J}p_{ij} y_{ij} \right\}.$$
Alternatively, you could combine the two $\sum_{i\in I}$:
$$\max_{x, y} \left\{\sum_{i\in I}\left(-f_i x_i + \sum_{j\in J}p_{ij} y_{ij}\right) \right\}.$$

Comment: so, x is a vector and y is a matrix?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.